# Windows 11 file explorer isn't showing the correct date modified

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, file-management

I have a directory that contains a number of log files. The files are created new every midnight, and continuously appended to every few seconds throughout the day. My expectation is that each time a new line is appended, the `date modified` of that file will be updated

Windows file explorer is configured to show the `date modified` for all of these files. However, it's frequently wrong by several hours. If I right click on the file, select `open` and then view the file with notepad (or similar) then the date modified displayed by file explorer changes to the current time.

I've tried clicking on the `refesh` button but this seems to update the list of files in the directory, *not* correct the times.

Is there any way to force file explorer to refresh the `date modified` on a regular basis?

Comment: My expectation is that each time a new line is appended, the date modified of that file will be updated   ....  Is your process closing (saving) the file each line and re-opening it?   I think you would need to do this to save the date on that line.